# Force refreshing upon hash param change using anchor tags

Tags: html

I used to have onclick events bound to my buttons so that it would change the hash params and then reload the page, but by doing so I got rid of the ability to <kbd>control + click</kbd> and <kbd>shift+click</kbd>. So I changed my buttons back to anchor tags with changing hash params, like so:

```
<a href="/alerts#?alert_type=Email">Email</a>
<a href="/alerts#?alert_type=Login">Login</a>
```

The problem now becomes, if the user is currently in the `/alerts` page then clicking these buttons only change the hash param but doesn't reload or anything of the sort. What approach should I take to handle this? My main requirements is:

- Keep <kbd>control + click</kbd> and <kbd>shift + click</kbd> functionality on buttons to open in new tab/new window
- Be able to "go to link" or reload page upon changing the hash params

Comment: `onhashchange`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange

Comment: have you tried this? `window.onhashchange = function(){window.location.reload()}`

Comment: @RizkiDPrast this seems to work, but this will also cause my page param changes to reload the whole page. Is there a way to get the previous state of the change? This way I may be able to pick the behavior I want based on whether it's a page # change or another parameter change